# Laravel Breeze w/Inertia & Vue Dashboard view User Data

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I'm using Laravel with Breeze along with Inertia and Vue.

I am looking at my Vue Dev tool while on the dashboard view and I can see my table schema and the user's strip ID. I would like more control over what is accessible here, however, I cannot find where the page is getting the data from. I can see the request, and even the query with clockwork, but I can't find where the request is being made within the code. Does anyone know where to look?[image: Vue Devtools showing table schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth.user` [shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data) comes from [here](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/a1358dc8a4d0d120a1aaa1160ff2b7cf62cd9f48/stubs/inertia-common/app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php#L34), in the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware.

```
    public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'auth' => [
                'user' => $request->user(),
            ],
            'ziggy' => function () use ($request) {
                return array_merge((new Ziggy)->toArray(), [
                    'location' => $request->url(),
                ]);
            },
        ]);
    }
```

This makes these items available in all Inertia responses.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you! I even looked at that middleware a few times, I guess I was expecting to be able to dump and die and get a hint for what I was looking for.